# Setting the tolerance for `Equal[]`

Tags: inequalities, numerical-value, approximation, precision-and-accuracy

I would like to control how `Equal[]` works and allow a certain error associated with it. I would like numerical values which are, say, within one-thousandth of one another to be considered the same.

For example, I would like

```
1.001 == 1.00
(*True*)
```

I've tried the following - but I'm worried this might not be possible.

```
SetPrecision[1.0000 == 1.0001, 2]
(* False *) 


SetAccuracy[1.0000 == 1.0001, 2]
(* False *) 

Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = Log10[2.^28]},
  Print[1.0001 == 1.000];
  ];
(* False *)
```

Comment: `a = SetPrecision[1.01, 2]; 
b = SetPrecision[1.00, 2]; 

a == b` evaluates to `True` or `SetPrecision[Hold[1.0000 == 1.0001], 2] // ReleaseHold`

Comment: Try ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = Log10[2.^53/10^4]},
 1.0001 == 1.000]``

Comment: Or perhaps more precisely, ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 
   Log10[2.^53/Max[1.0001, 1.000]/10^4]},
 1.0001 == 1.000]``